# Is there photo editing s/w that you can use on the camera vs. having to upload the photo to the PC?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I'm a grandmother that wants to use a camera for mostly pictures of the grandbabies, closeups in my garden of flowers, and shots in bright light around the pool and catching action shots.  I know I need image stabilization. I have a printer that accepts an SD card.  I want to print photos without having to upload the pictures to the computer.  I don't know if there is photo editing like a Picasso or Lightroom that can be within the camera for editing shots on the camera before they go directly to the printer?  I also need a large screen as my eyes aren't so good. My budget is only around $450.  With this information for my needs and budget, can you offer specific suggestions for the right camera for me?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I won't recommend specific products here, but you might actually be looking for a cell phone or a tablet instead of a camera. Most cell phones do not necessarily require you to use them as a cell phone, you can also without a subscription, use them as small, portable computers.

It is relatively easy to find cell phones, or to a certain extent also tablets if you want a larger display, with quite acceptable or good cameras. For these, there are a lot of different photo editing apps, which you can install and use directly on the device. You probably won't find a device with replaceable lenses and zooming capabilities, if present at all, are usually inferior.

It will be very difficult to find a dedicated camera, on which you can install a broad selection of additional software. Many cameras have some kind of image editing functions pre-installed, but the functions are often very limited. Often, you can only manipulate brightness, contrast and colour, crop the image or apply a few effect filters. For the same price, you can however, in general, expect much better optical and image quality from a dedicated camera than from a cell phone or a tablet.

You don't write why you want to avoid transferring the images to a pc and manipulate them there before printing, but if mobility is an issue and you already have a halfways decent cell phone, you do of course also have the option to transfer the images on-the-go from any camera to your cell phone, manipulate the images and then print from there.

Comment: I wouldn't say the option is there to transfer images on-the-go from *any* camera to a cell phone. It's more like *some* fairly recent cameras.